# Ajax Load more Script Bug?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Hey i test a loadmore script which i found online. 
But its not loading the Content when you done scrolling down. 
It is loading it when you complete scrolled up xD !

What is wrong ?

Here my Code

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).scroll(function()
{
    if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height())
    {
        $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').show();
        $.ajax({
        url: "loadmore.php",
        success: function(html)
        {
            if(html)
            {
                $("#postswrapper").append(html);
                $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').hide();
            }else
            {
                $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').html('<center>No more posts to show.</center>');
            }
        }
        });
    }
});
</script>

<div id="postswrapper">
   <div class="item">content</div>
   Hey<br>
   Hey<br>
   Hey<br>
   Hey<br>
   Hey<br>
   Hey<br>
 ---- MORE ADDED HERE BUT CUTTED OUT CAUSE WOULD BE VERY LONG! ----
   Hey<br>
   <div id="loadmoreajaxloader" style="display:none;"><center><img src="ajax-loader.gif" /></center></div>
</div>
```

Loadmore.php contains only a echo and then example div with contents ..

Console is also empty.

Thanks to everyone :)

***EDIT***

Here is a working [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/r25jpk55/1/) i copied that but still same Problem... Thanks to codegaze for this Fiddle.

***EDIT 2***
Here my Code which is working in JSFIDDLE!

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
            alert("This is the end");
        }
    });
});
</script>


<div id="postswrapper">
    <div class="item">content</div>Hey
    <br>Hey
    <br>Hey
    <br>Hey
    <br>Hey
    <br>Hey
    <br>Hey
    <br>Hey
    <br>Hey
    <br>Hey
    <br>Hey
    <br>Hey
    <br>Hey
    <br>Hey
    <br>Hey
    <br>Hey
    <br>Hey
    <br>Hey
    <br>Hey
    --- CUTTED OUT SOME MORE---
    <br>Hey
    <br>Hey
    <br>Hey
    <br>---- MORE ADDED HERE BUT CUTTED OUT CAUSE WOULD BE VERY LONG! ---- Hey
    <br>
    <div id="loadmoreajaxloader" style="display:none;">
        <center>
            <img src="ajax-loader.gif" />
        </center>
    </div>
```

I also downloaded the Source from the Example which i found online... and its working ... the only different i can see on the first View is that its includes Jquery 1.4.4    ????
[GITHUB EXAMPLE SOURCE](https://github.com/sdeering/5-jquery-infinite-scrolling-demos)

Comment: place an `alert()` in the first line inside your IF statement to see if it runs.

Comment: i addd it and it is running cause adding content too when you scroll at top

Comment: so that means your if statement is working correctly right? just trying to see where the error is happening

Comment: Yes down in @codegaze Answer there is a Fiddle i also update my Question with the working Fiddle .. i copied that Fiddle but also its only working when i scroll to top not when i scrooll to bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r25jpk55/1/) with plain html and works just fine. 
I think you should add a `$(document).ready()` as shown in my fiddle ;)

**UPDATE:** Construct your page with all the required tags to get a valid html page and your code will work. Your code is very simple, so it doesn't matter witch jquery version you will use.

This is a simple html page. Add your contents and check the result.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your fiddle now iam complete confused... 
i added Document read.. and your line and my Ajax... 
Still same Problem
Iam using Google Chrome maybe thats why ? Should i use IE ?

Comment: No it should be ok in all browsers. Can you post your new code? Try an example without the ajax functionality just a simple alert or console.log to see the result

Comment: Sure i added my new Code to Question. 
I did its still the same the Problem xD

Comment: ok. that is strange but to be sure.
1) Did the jsfiddle worked in your browser?
2) Did the simplified code you tried worked in your browser?
3) Can you post the full html page code?

Comment: Could you please post your full html page contents/code? It may even be your doctype or something 'irrelevant' with the script

Comment: Thats my complete code :) its a testing page so i dont work with Doctypes or something like this

Comment: okkkeyy... I replaced the Jquery Indlude from my (see in question) with this ...
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
And now it is working ? ... but i dont want to use 1.4.4 Oo